# nullpointerexception when trying to implement searchview as autocompletetextview

Tags: android, autocomplete, nullpointerexception, searchview

I'm trying to implement autocomplete `textview` functionality to my searchview since i find it easy as compared to content providers.The problem is that I'm getting `nullpointerexception` at `autoComplete.setAdapter(aAdapter)`.

This is part of my code: **Records.java**

```
        public class Records extends Fragment{
        String Name;
        GridView MyGrid;
        List<String> array=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> Location=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> Books=new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> Entertainment=new  ArrayList<String>();
        SearchView searchView ;
        String data;
        List<String> suggest;
        AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete;
        ArrayAdapter<String> aAdapter;


        //For Categories
        public String readJSONFeed(String URL){
            StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder();
            HttpClient httpClient=new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet=new HttpGet(URL);
            try{
                HttpResponse response=httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                StatusLine statusLine=response.getStatusLine();
                int StatusCode=statusLine.getStatusCode();
                if(StatusCode==200){
                    HttpEntity entity=response.getEntity();
                    InputStream inputStream=entity.getContent();
                    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    String line;
                    while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                        stringBuilder.append(line);
                    }
                    inputStream.close();

                }else{
                     Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
                    }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return stringBuilder.toString();
        }




        public class ReadJSONFeedTask2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String result= readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
                Log.d(" JSON: ", "> " + result);
                try{
                    //SubCategories subcategories=new SubCategories();
                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(result);
                    Log.d(" JSON: ", "> " + jsonArray.length());
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject json=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        suggest.add(json.getString("Name"));
                         Log.d(" AMNA: ", "> " + suggest.get(i));

                    }
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d("ReadJSONFeedTask1",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
                Log.d(" ACTIVITY: ", "> " + getActivity());
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                //aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,suggest);
                aAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.item,suggest);
                 Log.d(" ACTIVITY: ", "> " + getActivity());
                 autoComplete.setThreshold(2);
                 autoComplete.setAdapter(aAdapter);


            }


        }

        @Override

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview, container,false );
                    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


                    ActionBar actionbar = getActivity().getActionBar();
                    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    actionbar.show();

                    suggest = new ArrayList<String>();


            MyGrid=(GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute("http://10.0.2.2:63365/WebSite5/Registration/Categories.ashx");
            new ReadJSONFeedTask1().execute("http://10.0.2.2:63365/WebSite5/Registration/SubCategory.ashx");

            MyGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                        long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


 - 


----------


---------

           AlertDialog.Builder  dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                    if(position==0){


                        final String[] loc = Location.toArray(new String[Location.size()]);
                        Log.d(" Inside Alert: ", "> " + loc.length + Location.size());
                        dialog.setTitle("Choose Location by Category");
                        dialog.setItems(loc, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                searchView.setQueryHint("Search For "+loc[which]);

                            }
                        });

                        }
                        else if(position==1){
                        final String[] books=Books.toArray(new String[Books.size()]);
                        dialog.setTitle("Choose Book By Category").setItems(books, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                searchView.setQueryHint("Search For "+books[which]);
                                new ReadJSONFeedTask2().execute("http://10.0.2.2:63365/WebSite5/Registration/Books.ashx");
                            }
                        });

                        }
                        else if(position==2){
                            final String[] enter=Entertainment.toArray(new String[Entertainment.size()]);
                            dialog.setTitle("Choose Entertainment By Category").setItems(enter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    //searchView.setQueryHint("Search For "+enter[which]);

                                }
                            });

                            }


                        dialog.create();
                        dialog.show();

                }

            });
            return v;

        }



    @Override

        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(
         Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        // Get the SearchView and set the searchable configuration
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getActivity(). getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
             searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.help).getActionView();
           searchView.setIconified(false);

            searchView.setQueryHint("Search for recomendations");
            autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

            // Assumes current activity is the searchable activity
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
             // Do not iconify the widget; expand it by default
    }


    }
```

**Res/xml/Searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:label="@string/app_label"
     android:hint="@string/search_hint"
     >


</searchable>
```

**Res/menu/main.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

   <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="search" 
          android:showAsAction="always" 
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
          android:actionLayout="@layout/searchable" /> 



    </item>
   <item android:id="@+id/home" android:title="refresh"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_refresh"
      android:showAsAction="always"  />


</menu>
```

**Res/layout/searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
        android:text="AutoCompleteTextView"
        android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect" >

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Logcat:**

```
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at com.example.swipetabs.Records$ReadJSONFeedTask2.onPostExecute(Records.java:205)
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at com.example.swipetabs.Records$ReadJSONFeedTask2.onPostExecute(Records.java:1)
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-02 08:05:41.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1594):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Edited Logcat:

```
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.example.swipetabs.Records.onCreateView(Records.java:232)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:461)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1064)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:911)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1432)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:847)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4827)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15513)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-02 09:08:08.641: E/AndroidRuntime(910):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Changed onCreateView():

```
@Override

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview, container,false );
                    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


                    ActionBar actionbar = getActivity().getActionBar();
                    getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                    actionbar.show();

                    suggest = new ArrayList<String>();
 autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
MyGrid=(GridView)v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
            new ReadJSONFeedTask().execute("http://10.0.2.2:63365/WebSite5/Registration/Categories.ashx");
            new ReadJSONFeedTask1().execute("http://10.0.2.2:63365/WebSite5/Registration/SubCategory.ashx");

            MyGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){


                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position,
                        long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

           AlertDialog.Builder  dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

                    if(position==0){


                        final String[] loc = Location.toArray(new String[Location.size()]);
                        Log.d(" Inside Alert: ", "> " + loc.length + Location.size());
                        dialog.setTitle("Choose Location by Category");
                        dialog.setItems(loc, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                searchView.setQueryHint("Search For "+loc[which]);

                            }
                        });

                        }
                        else if(position==1){
                        final String[] books=Books.toArray(new String[Books.size()]);
                        dialog.setTitle("Choose Book By Category").setItems(books, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                searchView.setQueryHint("Search For "+books[which]);
                                new ReadJSONFeedTask2().execute("http://10.0.2.2:63365/WebSite5/Registration/Books.ashx");
                            }
                        });

                        }
                        else if(position==2){
                            final String[] enter=Entertainment.toArray(new String[Entertainment.size()]);
                            dialog.setTitle("Choose Entertainment By Category").setItems(enter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    //searchView.setQueryHint("Search For "+enter[which]);

                                }
                            });

                            }


                        dialog.create();
                        dialog.show();

                }

            });
            return v;

        }
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, exception is thrown on this line: `autoComplete.setThreshold(2);`. `autocomplete` seems to be null. You need to initialize it in your `onCreateView()` before executing `ReadJSONFeedTask2`.

Comment: i also tried initializing 'autoComplete' in 'onCreateView()' but the problem remains.I've attached the new logcat.

Comment: show changed onCreateView =)

Comment: you just copy-paste your code from onCreateOptionsMenu, so there is no searchView variable in onCreateMethod. I'm edited my answer, check it

Answer (score 1):

You initializing your autoComplete variable in onCreateOptionsMenu method, wich is called when menu is shown

```
autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
```

you should initialize it before.

Try to do thomething like this. Make class variable ArrayAdapter to keep result from you ReadJSONFeedTask2

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> YourAdapter = null;

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    YourAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.item,suggest);
}
```

and than in your onCreateOptionsMenu method add this adapter

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    ...
    autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);

    autoComplete.setThreshold(2);
    autoComplete.setAdapter(YourAdapter);
    ...
```

}

Comment: i did exactly what you said but I'm still getting null pointer exception at 'autoComplete.setThreshold'